# Ionic 3 - Play video downloaded from site and stored on device dataDirectory

Tags: ionic3

I just want to ask if what might be the solution on my problem.
I have a video file on my API server, and when I request, it returns the path of my video. My code successfully copied and downloaded the video. But when I try to make the `file.dataDirectory + filename` as the source to my video tag, it ain't playing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/play-mp4-video-on-android-and-ios-from-local-folder/15737/4

You can use the (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) to write and read the video file (base64 in case -> readAsDataURL).

I found this. But you can not use with large video files (15MB>).

So far, I have not been able to read larger local videos directly from the HTML5 player, apparently some old code does not work anymore, but I'm still researching about it.